# strange SQL statement from Oracle JDBC driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

An AWR report from monitoring my Java application shows a strange SQL statement:

```
select HEXTORAW(value$) from props$
where name = 'NO_USERID_VERIFIER_SALT'
ORDER BY value$
```

I don't know what it is, but the DBA insists that it is coming from my application, so I am guessing the Oracle JDBC driver itself is responsible for this, not my own application code.

Any idea what this is, and whether should I care about it or not?

Comment: What part of the query don't you understand? Or is it the origion of the complete query?

Comment: I don't understand the origin of the query, and what purpose does it serve

Comment: Don't know where it comes from but it reads the salt (that is probably used for encryption or hashing) from the oracle properties table. Try to grab a SQL profiler to see when this happens in your app.